# Encountering Rviz issues while trying to create a map with Hector SLAM

Tags: automation, ros, lidar, slam, rviz

[Rviz screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMbKL.png)I am currently trying to run Rviz to create a map of my apartment. I finally got everything to run without errors, my Lidar is outputting data properly (I double checked by looking at the raw data), and Rviz is opening when I input the code "roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch". WhenRviz opens though a map is not created and there is just a dark grey square over the grid. Am I missing something or is something else going wrong? If you have any insight on what might be happening I would very much appreciate your input. I'm attaching a screenshot of what my rviz screen looks like.

I tried just letting rviz run on my system in hopes that if I gave it more time the map would compile but in 30 minutes the map didn't change even slightly.

Comment: Are you actually getting map data over the map topic?

Comment: @BTables I know the Lidar is outputting data correctly but how can I check if I'm getting map data?

Comment: `rostopic echo` the map topic in the command line.

Comment: @BTables When I use the command to check the output is a repeated -1, does that mean the data is being published?

Comment: Also if it is, and the map data is being published what might be going wrong?

Comment: Yes, if you see any output that means a map is being published. If it's not changing it either means your lidar data isn't making it to the mapping node(something like a topic remap problem) or you have an invalid transform(you would probably see warnings about this)

Comment: @BTables I attached a ss and in it it says no TF data does this does that mean its an invalid transform? Also in both scenarios how would I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Yes, it means there is no tf data for the `map` frame. You should be trying to view the frame in whatever the map messages are being published in. You can find this by looking at the `rostopic echo` and seeing what's listed in the `header` message.